# Running mean with condition in R?

Tags: r

It is easy to compute the running mean using "caTools" but I want only if there is at least 3 values in the window, otherwise return NA

```
    library("caTools") 
    x=c(56,NA,4,6,2,1,NA,NA,NA,5,2,5,6,4,7,5,2,NA) 
    runmean(x,5)
```

Comment: You can make use of `ifelse`

Comment: I think you might already have an answer, but it would help if you showed your desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, I define a function that counts the non-`NA` elements and if it is less than three returns `NA`. If, however, it is greater than or equal to 3 it returns the mean.

```
foo <- function(x)ifelse(sum(!is.na(x)) < 3, NA, mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Next, I apply the function using `rollapply` from the `zoo` package,

```
rollapply(x, width = 5, FUN = foo)
```

giving the following results:

```
#[1] 17.00  3.25  3.25  3.00    NA    NA    NA  4.00  4.50  4.40  4.80  5.40  4.80  4.50
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...?

```
> library(zoo)
> rollapply(x, 3, mean)
 [1]       NA       NA 4.000000 3.000000       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA 4.000000 4.333333 5.000000 5.666667
[14] 5.333333 4.666667       NA
```